# Issue with min cost path

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, greedy

I was solving min cost path problem through dynamic approach but suddenly I realised that greedy approach is also working. 
I applied greedy like this :
choose the min of bottom, right and diagonal cost and move in the min cost path.

1  2 3

4 8 2

1 5 3

where numbers are cost which will be added to the required cost if we include that point.
path from 1 to 3 is 12 through greedy is 8.

If my approach doesn't follow all examples, the  what is that example?

Comment: what are the numbers supposed to mean?

Comment: @ThijsSteel I've edited it now

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: In this example, it just happens that the greedy solution finds the correct answer. Could you be more descriptive in your question?

Answer (score 0):

How about a map such as:

```
1  1  1
2  10 10
1  1  1
```

Your greedy approach will end up taking 1+1+1+10+1, instead of 1+2+1+1

Answer (score 0):

Greedy algorithms can be 'beaten' by giving them a long meandering path with several small steps:

```
2 2 e
2 ∞ 0
s 3 0
```

In this case, going from s to e will require either

- The greedy solution: See that 2 is smaller and slog through several three 2's for a total cost of 6
- A dynamic solution: See that after the three there is an easy path for a total cost of 3.

Also, I'd take a look at how your two algorithms define length. The optimal path is actually 1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 3 which has a cost of 10. If your dynamic solution isn't returning that, it may indicate that something else is going on.